# Writing and reading a row array (nx1) to a binary file in Python with struct pack

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, binary

I'm having a lot of trouble writing to and reading from a binary file when working with a `nx1` row vector that has been written to a binary file using `struct.pack`. The file structure looks like this (given an argument `data` that is of type `numpy.array`) :

```
test.file
--------

[format_code = 3] : 4 bytes (the code 3 means a vector) - fid.write(struct.pack('i',3))
[rows] : 4 bytes (fid.write(struct.pack('i',sz[0])) where sz = data.shape
[cols] : 4 bytes (fid.write(struct.pack('i',sz[1]))
[data] : type double = 8 bytes * (rows * cols)
```

Unfortunately, since these files are mostly written in MATLAB, where I have a working class that reads and writes these fields, I can't only write the amount of rows (I need columns as well even if a column does only = 1).

I've tried a few ways to pack `data`, none of which have worked when trying to unpack it (assume I've opened my file denoted by `fid` in `'rb'/'wb'` and have done some error checking):

```
# write data
sz = data.shape
datalen=8*sz[0]*sz[1]
fid.write(struct.pack('i',3)) # format code
fid.write(struct.pack('i',sz[0])) # rows
fid.write(struct.pack('i',sz[1])) # columns

### write attempt ###
for i in xrange(sz[0]):
    for j in xrange(sz[1]):
        fid.write(struct.pack('d',float(data[i][j]))) # write in 'c' convention, so we transpose

### read attempt ###
format_code = struct.unpack('i',fid.read(struct.calcsize('i')))[0]
rows = struct.unpack('i',fid.read(struct.calcsize('i')))[0]
cols = struct.unpack('i',fid.read(struct.calcsize('i')))[0]
out_datalen = 8 * rows * cols # size of structure
output_data=numpy.array(struct.unpack('%dd' % out_datalen,fid.read(datalen)),dtype=float)
```

So far, when reading, my output has just seemingly been multiplied by random things. I don't know whats happening.

I found another similar question, and so I wrote my data as such:

```
fid.write(struct.pack('%sd' % len(data), *data))
```

However, when reading it back using:

```
numpy.array(struct.unpack('%sd' % out_datalen,fid.read(datalen)),dtype=float)
```

I get nothing in my array.

Similarly, just doing:

```
fid.write(struct.pack('%dd' % datalen, *data))
```

and reading it back with:

```
numpy.array(struct.unpack('%dd' % out_datalen,fid.read(datalen)),dtype=float)
```

also gives me an empty array. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do note that bare `'i'` does not mean "a 4-byte integer"; it means the C type `int` which can be of any size. To write anything at all in portable manner, you need to use a [flag character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Comment: Please post *complete* code to reproduce the problem. We now need to write lots of boilerplate to test your assumptions. See also [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: What's the result of the various `struc.unpack...` expressions - before passing through `np.array`?

Comment: Look at using `np.fromfile`